# Compare data from two experiments within single logistic regression to determine effect of experimental design?

Tags: regression, experiment-design, meta-analysis, post-hoc

I've run two studies.

Study 1 (N = 112) examines the effects of two variables (A and B), each of which have two levels (a1, a2; b1, b2). For each variable, I'm interested in the effect those different levels have on target selections (0 or 1).

Study 2 (N = 72) examines *just* the effect of variable B: subjects are only exposed to b1 and b2.

The stimuli and task is exactly the same for both studies. However, subjects saw half the number of Variable B items in Study 1 as they did in Study 2. The sample is totally different: no subjects took both Study 1 and Study 2.

I have analyzed both these studies (separately) using a mixed-effects logistic regression model, predicting target selections from variable-level. (For study 1, I fit two separate models, one for each variable).

I now want to determine what effect the presence of variable A had on target selections for variable B, by directly comparing the two sets of results. So far I have done this by combining the Study 2 dataset and the variable B data from Study 1, and predicting target selections from variable-level, Study(1 or 2) and their interaction. My thinking was that if the presence of Variable A had an effect on target selections for Variable B, this would show up as a main effect of Study. If target selections for the two levels of Variable B were differently affected by the presence/absence of Variable A, this should show up as an interaction effect between Study and variable-level.

My question is pretty basic: given that these data come from two different experiments, is it justifiable to combine the analysis in this way? My concern is that this is data from two totally different populations -- but both studies were conducted under highly similar conditions, and I figured that some of the variance associated with individual subjects would be accounted for by including random intercepts and random by-variable-level slopes for participant.

Many many thanks for any help!